# set subchild not to indent in qtreewidget when I expand them

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` and I want children of a `QTreeWidgetItem` not indent when I expand them. I want to set the line only for top items. The first screenshot demonstrates what I would like to have, and the second what I am currently having. Would you please help me with how to change it to be like the first one? Thank you in advance!

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture![][1]]

Comment: Nothing is better than good old `file:///home/` link ;)

Comment: yes, sry, i edit it :D

Comment: You can use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#indentation-prop to control indentation, but you cannot do it with specific elements, ie. you cannot set zero indentation to only leaf items, leaving others indented. I don't think you can do it with regular `QTreeWidget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible by `QTreeWidget` since you can only set the indentation globally. You would need to create your own class implementing this logic, e.g. `QListWidgets` connected to each other, or just a brand new tree widget implementation. You could also of course improve the existing QTreeWidget and send a patch.

Comment: i want to implement my own qtreewidget, but i dont know how to change toplevelitems and their subchilds indentation or how to set line only for top level items, would you please help me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Use QTreeView and in customized QStyledItemDelegate.paint(), make the sub-child item widget move slightly to the left.

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    self.initStyleOption(option, index)
    
    # top-level item
    if index.parent().isValid() == False:
        return super().paint(painter, option, index)

    # sub-child item
    item = index.model().itemFromIndex(index)
    item_widget = any_method_to_get_your_subchild_widget()
    item_widget.setGeometry(option.rect.adjusted(-1*option.widget.indentation(), 0, 0, 0))
    item_widget.show()

    pass
```